# Долой метку [software] и подобные безликие метки

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Здесь все вопросы (почти) про [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software). Предлагаю эту метку сжечь. Если кто не согласен, объясните её предназначение и область применения.

---

Также поддерживаю [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be), [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) (автор предложения @NickVolynkin).

Comment: В ту же печь [tag:по] и [tag:программы]

Comment: @NickVolynkin до кучи и [tag:веб-программирование] с [tag:web-разработка].

Comment: @alexolut вот про веб-программирование с веб-разработкой я б пожалуй не был так категоричен. Можно сжечь, но можно и облагородить

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму В чём эти метки помогают? Полагаю, около 50-60% вопросов на сайте можно отнести к [tag:веб-программирование] и [tag:web-разработка]. К примеру почти все вопросы про [tag:php], [tag:javascript] и т.д. И что, так будет лучше?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму без упоминания конкретной технологии от таких меток проку мало. Более того, уже есть метка [tag:web].

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму А как можно облагородить?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ну если относить к метке "веб-разработка" не специфику конкретного языка, а некие обобщенные вопросы вроде этого: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536784/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-html5-websocket-long-short-polling-ajax-webrtc-server-sent-events, то она имеет право на жизнь

Comment: @alexolut, о еще одна странная метка с неясной судьбой)

Comment: @alexolut [tag:web] тоже в печь?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму это вопрос и без [tag:веб-разработка] прекрасно живёт. И не надо обобщённых вопросов, они очень редко полезны бывают. Намного чаще приходится закрывать или удалять. И обобщённые метки способствуют таким вопросам.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я по web не спец, надо кого-то более просвещенного для принятия решения по сжиганию именно этой метки.

Comment: Надо чат по обсуждению вопросов кремации меток открыть, если ещё нет.

Comment: @alexolut В печь короче. Там по ней тот ещё зоопарк: [tag:php], [tag:python], [tag:c#] и т.д..

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov количество меток на вопросе ограничено потому что, а то я бы влепил)  Лично я нормально отношусь к обобщенным вопросам, но мнение сообщества может не совпадать со мнением утки)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov за удаление software я голосовал, за удаление "веб-разработки" я не голосовал, вопрос таки лучше не править таким образом

Comment: [tag:веб-разработка] или аналог нужна в качестве уточняющей метки. Например, на питоне можно писать веб, а можно и не веб. Пара меток [tag:python] [tag:веб-разработка] вполне может быть уместной.

Comment: Перенёс веб-программирование в отдельный [вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4339/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: @Nofate Прелагаю, [обсудить](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4340/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9) ваш аргумент

Answer (score 2):

Метки [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software), [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be), [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) в большинстве вопросов действительно ставить не стоит. Но они могут быть полезны, если речь идёт о программах в целом, а не о написании программ. Например, о всяких режимах эмуляции и виртуализации и т. д.

Полагаю, надо эти метки синонимизировать к одной, которая будет ясно давать понять, зачем она нужна. Поскольку у меня нечего лучше, чем [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) не придумывается, предлагайте варианты в комментариях.

Comment: Без нормального описания - опять будут лепить куда попало

Comment: @Grundy, нужно нормальное название и ещё описание. Предлагай варианты названия для начала, а с описанием потом разберёмся.

Comment: "Программы" это хорошо уже тем, что по-русски. Алиасом можно нацеплять какие угодно слова на английском.

Comment: Есть примеры хороших вопросов с этими метками, без которых этот вопрос будет неполноценен?